# Basic authentication for Ajax and Jersey web service

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have protected a web service using @RolesAllowed({"Customer"}). I have successfully tested the code and security configuration using the Jersey client API. Now, I am trying to access the same service from JavaScript using AJAX. I set the credentials in the open method of XMLHttpRequest:

```
xhr.open("GET", url, true, "bob", "paasss");
```

This is simply not going to work. Let me explain:

XHR first sends a request without the Authorization header. Only if it encounters a 401 response status *and* the "WWW-Authenticate" header that it retries the request and this time sends the Authorization header. When a service is protected using @RolesAllowed, Jersey sends a 403 status. Hence, Authorization header is never sent.

Only way I can get this to work is set the Authorization header myself:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic Ym9iOnBhc3N3MHJk");
```

Is this the acceptable way of doing things? Can I somehow make Jersey return 401 instead of 403 as well as the "WWW-Authenticate" header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding auth constraint in web.xml for the desired URL pattern. For example:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

That way it won't even reach Jersey if no user is authenticated - the container itself will return 401.

If that's not an option for you, you can either extend RolesAllowedFilterFactory to do the additional check on whether SecurityContext.getPrincipal() returns null and generate 401 in that case or simply add ContainerRequestFilter which does that.